# Radio buttons are not displayed on iPad

Tags: pdf, forms

I have created a form with radio buttons. Everything looks fine in Chrome, Edge and Firefox. As soon as I open it on an iPad the buttons are missing and the marker changes. I have tried a lot of examples, but without success.

here is an example code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}    
        \ChoiceMenu[radio, radiosymbol=\ding{108},bordercolor={black}, name=Option1]{\textbf{Option 1:}} {A,B,C}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Chrome

[image]

iPad

[image]

I tested it with multiply Apps on iPad. Always the same result... Acrobat, Foxit PDF Editor and the default viewer from iOS

Comment: Welcome. // That statement is a bit too broad. Can you please indicate the Apps you tried on iPad in your question? Did you try different webbrowsers, like Firefox, and the Acrobat reader?

Comment: not just anyone ? :-(